# Superfish jquery plugin, highlight selected menu item

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, css, superfish

I am just wondering what is the more "not hardcoded" approach i can use to make current selected menu highlighted when using superfish plugin.

For example this one http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css looking very "hardcoded way" of doing this.

May be some one may suggest something more smart?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it - get the current page after the last / in the url and highlight the link that matches it. eg. this page would would return `superfish-jquery-plugin-highlight-selected-menu-item`

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
$('ul#main-navigation li a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Instead of adding the 'active' class, I added the 'sfHover' class and removed the default setting hoverClass:"sfHover" from the plugins.js file or where the plugin is initialized with the default settings

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unless you're using a dynamic language to render you pages, it's difficult to provide a neat and tidy solution to this.

One possibility is to use the anchors' `href` attribute, which would be equal to part of the `window.location.pathname` string.

For instance, assume your site is at the root of a server, with HTML pages called `index.html`, `work.html` etc. Then, you can grab the `pathname` (the part of the URL after the domain name) and match that to the anchor's `href` attribute.

Your navigation could look like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And your Javascript could look like this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
// trim the first slash
var substr = pathname.substr(1);
$('nav').find('li a[href="' + substr + '"]').addClass('current');
```

So when you're on `index.html`, the variable `substr` is equal to `index.html`, so the list item with `data-page-name` equal to `index.html` gets the class `current`.

This solution is OK in that you only need one navigation tree, as you don't have to edit *every page* to add an ID or class to an element. You *do* find yourself in a mess if you change a filename though, because you have to change the `data-page-name` attribute in every file (although you'd have to change the anchor `href` anyway).